# Factory in Angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, factory

I'm trying to use a factory in angularjs, but it's showing nothing on page, with no errors being displayed on console.

Can anyone point out the mistake I am making?

[Here is plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/vxB2pRim7USwfXPL4lVA?p=preview).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); 
app.factory('customersFactory',function($scope){

   var customers = [{
    id:1,
    name: 'James',
    city: 'Seattle',
    orderTotal: 9.546,
    joined: '2012-02-05',
    orders:[{
      id:1,
      product:'Shoes',
      total:9.9665
    }]
  }, {
    id:2,
    name: 'Sarah',
    city: 'Dallas',
    orderTotal: 3.653,
    joined: '2010-08-07',
    orders:[{
      id:2,
      product:'Sandal',
      total:8.3465
    }]
  }, {
    id:3,
    name: 'Tom',
    city: 'Troy',
    orderTotal: 8.346,
    joined: '2011-04-09',
    orders:[{
      id:3,
      product:'Sneakers',
      total:6.3427
    }]
  }, {
    id:4,
    name: 'Ling',
    city: 'Columbus',
    orderTotal: 5.549,
    joined: '2014-03-10',
    orders:[{
      id:4,
      product:'belt',
      total:8.9674
    }]
  }];


   var factory={};
   factory.getCustomers = function(){
      return customers;
   };

   factory.getCustomer = function(customerId){
     for (var i = 0, len = customers.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (customers[i].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
          return customers[i];
          }

    }
     return {};
   }

   return factory;

 });
```

Comment: How do i test the differents route into a plunker ? Actually your <ng-view> is empty. The routing isn't doing his work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue I see is you're creating a new module for every controller and factory. This should reside under the same module. To do that, for example, the `customerController` should be instantiated with a simple `app.controller('customerController'....)` and the factory `app.factory('customersFactory'...)` etc

the second issue is you are trying to inject `$scope` into factory which you cannot do. See this updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/0N47C3yFq58H5AyCoh5a?p=preview

I am aware of being able to use multiple modules in a single app, but for what you're doing that is not necessary. If you must, you have defined `var app` twice. Once in `app.js` and another in `customersFactory.js`

Start the `customersFactory` to something like below and it will work

```
var fac = angular.module('customersFactory',[]);
fac.factory('customersFactory',function(){
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I try to do as you said. View Orders doesn't work.

Comment: `ordersController` should have `$scope.customer = customersFactory.getCustomer(customerId);` not `$scope.customer = customersFactory.getCustomer();`

Comment: its ok, it happens. Please mark the answer correct if this has helped you.